# Error while trying to run Spark

Tags: linux, git, apache-spark

I am new to spark. I have downloaded the spark version 1.3.1 prebuilt for hadoop version 2.6 . I extracted and navigated to the folder and typed in the below command :
  ./bin/spark-shell
for which i get an error which says spark-shell command not found. I did the same on windows using git bash for which I get an error saying

spark-submit : line 26 tput command not found

is there something else I need to do before trying to run spark?

Comment: The 'command not found' error may happen in linux if you try to run a 32-bit executable file on a 64-bit machine. Run `file ./bin/spark-shell` and `uname -a` to see if the executable is compatible with your machine.

Comment: the file command just displays it as a c source and not as any executable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows, in regular cmd prompt, use `spark-shell.cmd`.
On Linux, in terminal, `cd` to your Spark root (yours should be named `spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6` if you kept the original name) and then execute:

```
./bin/spark-shell
```

Have you recently changed your .bash_profile? Any problems with other commands? Try just typing e.g. `tar` in your shell. All good or not?

**EDIT** *(after the first comment below):*

Here's how to start the REPL on **Linux** (logging level set to errors only).
`Spark` is just a symlink to a Spark version I want to use, ignore that and take it as your Spark home dir:

[image]

And here's **Windows**:
[image]

You almost cannot do anything wrong how straightforward it is :)

Comment: on typing spark-shell.cmd while in the spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6 i get an error saying that 'spark-shell.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command. if I navigate to spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin and type the same thing I get a pathnot found error.

Comment: Take a look at images.

Comment: And how about answering those questions I asked?

Comment: sorry....I haven't changed anything in my .bash_profile and all commands seem to work fine. it just does not seem to recognize the  ./bin/spark-shell command though.

Comment: Linux: Can you post the output of 'ls -la' fired from the 'bin' folder?

Comment: it worked on both! you were right! the permissions of the executables were messed up. it worked when I changed it. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 2):

In linux

> 1. Install scala
> 2. Install git
> 3. Build Spark

**Build Spark:**

```
$ wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.5.0/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
$ tar xvf spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
$ sudo mv spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6 /usr/local/spark
$ /usr/local/spark/bin/spark-shell
```

Answer (score -2):

After extracting and navigating to the folder you need to build the Apache Spark by this command:

```
mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

where you need to install maven(mvn) by

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

Comment: He said it's a prebuilt version.